# The group $O(n)$ is contained in a sphere of radius $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I have this exercise where I have to show that the group $O(n)$ is contained in a sphere of radius $n$ and centered on the origin, but I keep getting the wrong answer.

Previously in the exercise I showed that the inner product of two matrices can be defined as:

$$ \langle X,Y \rangle = \text{tr}(XY^T)$$

Suppose $ X $ is orthogonal, that is, $XX^T=I_n$ (the $n\times n$ identity matrix). Then the norm of $X$ is:

$$ ||X||^2 = \langle X, X \rangle = \text{tr}(XX^T)=\text{tr}(I_n) = n \implies ||X||=\sqrt n$$

which is a sphere of radius $\sqrt n$, not $n$, meaning I'm making a very stupid mistake somewhere.

Comment: Well, if the radius is $\sqrt{n}$ then it is actually contained in a sphere of radius $n$...

Comment: No, you're not.